# Shape keys bag?

Tags: shape-keys

So I was sculpting a face and then decided to have some fun with it, using shape keys.
And now, after turning a shape key off I have this =(  Some vertices snapped at the world origin

Is this a bug or my mistake? =( Is this somehow reversible?

No modifiers, dynamic topology sculpt

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Shape keys have references on the ordered list of vertices of the mesh, so they have to be used moving vertices only, not adding or deleting them (as dynamic sculpt does) because this alters the vertices order in the list, and breaks the shapes.

If you want to revert, the only things you can try are recover files functions in the file menu (or pressing Ctrl Z as many times as your system preferences allow).